# DateTime being passed to insert query in PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys it may have been asked before but I am still stuck with a peculiar issue.

I am trying to Pass a dateTime object to my mysql insert statement but it always tells me there is an error  namely:

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

```
$dateToPass = new DateTime('now');
                        //$dateToPass = $dateToPass->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
                        //inserting values
                        $SQLstring="Insert into Request(cust_num,request_date,item_description,item_weight,pickup_address,pickup_suburb,
                        pickup_date,pickup_time,receiver_name,delivery_address,delivery_suburb,delivery_state) 
                        values(27,$dateToPass,'$desc',$weight,'$address','$suburb','$date',                         '$time','$rname','$raddress','$rsuburb','$rstate');";
                        $queryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
                        Or die ("<p>Unable to query the Customer table.</p>"."<p>Error code ". mysqli_errno($DBConnect). ": ".mysqli_error($DBConnect)). "</p>";
```

Where $dateToPass is a datetime field in my database.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: remove the comment and it should be `$dateToPass = $dateToPass->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: tried that all it does say that it could not convert the date to specified format.

Comment: Guys I figured it out apparently the $date I was passing in the query had to be a string but it was a date object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot send `DateTime` object as string. Try converting it to string as MySQL expects.

```
$dateToPass = new DateTime('now');
$dateToPass = $dateToPass->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Alternatively if you are always going to store current datetime you can use the MySQL [NOW()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) like

```
$SQLstring="Insert into Request(cust_num,request_date,item_description,item_weight,pickup_address,pickup_suburb,
pickup_date,pickup_time, receiver_name,delivery_address,
delivery_suburb,delivery_state)  
values(27,NOW(),'$desc',$weight,'$address','$suburb','$date', '$time','$rname','$raddress','$rsuburb','$rstate');";
```